# AppleScript Error -2710

Tags: applescript

The below code is throwing a error in AppleScript. I get `error "iTerm got an error: Can’t make class «class Ptrm»." number -2710 from «class Ptrm» to class`. Any suggestions what may be causing it? I am totally new to AppleScript but I was handed this possibly outdated script and need it to run so that it will spawn the below 5 operations in iTerm. All insight welcome! Thanks

```
tell application "iTerm"
set t to (make new «class Ptrm»)
tell t
    activate «class Cssn»
    «event ITRMLNCH» given «class Pssn»:"Default Session"
    tell the last «class Pssn»
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"vagrant ssh"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"cd /vagrant"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"./devsettings.sh scripts/runserver.py"
        delay 1
    end tell
    «event ITRMLNCH» given «class Pssn»:"Default Session"
    tell the last «class Pssn»
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"vagrant ssh"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"cd /vagrant"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"./localsettings.sh ./scripts/runcelery.py worker -c 10 -A plug.tasks -Q celery,pushq"
        delay 1
    end tell
    «event ITRMLNCH» given «class Pssn»:"Default Session"
    tell the last «class Pssn»
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"vagrant ssh"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"cd /vagrant/messaging"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"python2.7 directoryServer.py"
        delay 1
    end tell
    «event ITRMLNCH» given «class Pssn»:"Default Session"
    tell the last «class Pssn»
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"vagrant ssh"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"cd /vagrant/messaging"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"python2.7 iHttp.py"
        delay 1
    end tell
    «event ITRMLNCH» given «class Pssn»:"Default Session"
    tell the last «class Pssn»
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"vagrant ssh"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"cd /vagrant/messaging/src"
        «event ITRMWrte» given «class iTxt»:"go run wsServer.go"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Displayed raw data like `«class Ptrm»` rather than the expected readable terminology indicates that the compiled script doesn't match the current dictionary of the application.

Comment: Okay, so any idea how you'd go about fixing it?

Comment: Try to find out the commands and classes with the help of the current dictionary and rewrite the script.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried resetting your computer's libraries? 
Enter the following command into iTerm, then recompile your script and see if you are still getting this error.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```